# Merge Dataframes with MultiIndex in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge, multi-index

I am attempting to merge two dataframes. Each of which has 100k rows.

```
df1 => Columns = ID1, ID2, Value1

df2 => Columns = ID1, ID2, Value2
```

I can do this by either doing

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['ID1','ID2'])
```

This works fairly efficiently.

However, I thought it would be faster if I first set an index - specifically a MultiIndex. So I did:

```
df1 = df1.set_index(['ID1', 'ID2'])
df2 = df2.set_index(['ID1', 'ID2'])
```

Then I did my merge by doing:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

To my surprise, this was a lot slower than the first approach. I was hoping for it to be at least the same, or hopefully faster.

What am I misunderstanding?